# Appending Data to an Array in Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, arrays, swift, parse-platform, cloud

I am writing a function of Parse Cloud Code to append a double to an array for a voting system:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addVote", function(request){

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var id = request.params.key
    var vote = request.params.vote

    var query = new Parse.Query("Post");
    query.equalTo("objectID", id);
    query.find({
        success: function(poll){
            poll.add("votes", vote)
            poll.save();
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.error("Got an error");
        }
    });
});
```

I'm calling the function by using:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("addComment", withParameters: ["key" : key, "vote": self.vote)]
```

I'm getting the response "TypeError: Object  has no method 'add'".  What am I doing wrong that is causing this error?

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing `]`. Is that just here?

Comment: What is `poll`? Where do you define it? Why do you think it *does* have a method `add`?

Comment: To address the comments from @AaronBrager:  I was only missing the closing ] in this post.  I have updated my question to be more accurate.  In the js, I was under the impression that "poll" would be the object returned if the query for a post was successful ("poll" would be a "Post" object which contains an array "votes").  Is this correct?

Comment: Also, I thought the `add` method was used to append values to an array in javascript.  Is that not true?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addVote", function(request){

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var id = request.params.key
    var answer = request.params.vote

    var query = new Parse.Query("Post");
    query.get(id, {
        success: function(post){
            post.add("votes", vote);
            post.save();
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.error("Got and error");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below is example for update data users. this code 100% work tested on back4app.com

before using this code, you must declare your variable like below
export async function prepareForSending(form) {
  // available modes: text, numbers, files, pointers and for others you need to

```
custome some of my code with your needs
  let FORM = [
    {
      mode: "text",
      object: "name",
      value: form.name
    },
    {
      mode: "text",
      object: "phone",
      value: form.phone
    },
    {
      mode: "text",
      object: "address",
      value: form.address
    },
    {
      mode: "text",
      object: "clientStatus",
      value: form.clientStatus.selected
    },
    {
      mode: "pointer",
      object: "role",
      value: {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "_Role",
        objectId: form.roles.selected
      }
    }
  ];

  return FORM;
}
```

and then, now you can use code below

```
export function ParseUserManualUpdater(ID, DATA) {
  //ID is a users objectId target
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
      id: ID,
      data: DATA
    };
    const Cloud = await Parse.Cloud.run("usersUpdater", params);
    if (Cloud == "success") {
      resolve(true);
    } else {
      resolve(false);
    }
  });
}
```

and upload this code to your code cloud

```
Parse.Cloud.define("usersUpdater", function(request, response) {
  //  how can I use GET parameters here??
  var ID = request.params.id;
  var DATA = request.params.data;

  const User = new Parse.User();
  const query = new Parse.Query(User);
  query.get(ID).then(user => {
    for (let i = 0; i < DATA.length; i++) {
      let mode = DATA[i].mode;
      let object = DATA[i].object;
      let value = DATA[i].value;
      if (mode == "text") {
        user.set(object, value);
      } else if (mode == "number") {
        user.set(object, Number(value));
      } else if (mode == "pointer") {
        user.set(object, value);
      } else if (mode == "file") {
        user.set(
          object,
          new Parse.File(value.file.name, {
            base64: value.file.base64
          })
        );
      }
    }
    user.save(null, {useMasterKey: true}).then(
      resSucces => {
        response.success("success");
      },
      resError => {
        response.error("error");
      }
    );
  });
});
```

im hope, my code can help someone there